# How to create a regex to validate user expression that includes some commands?

Tags: regex

I need to validate a user input that can include parentheses, the word 'or' and the word 'and'.

The rules are simple:

1- Parentheses can be used anywhere but opening parentheses must have closing one (I might validate this part with code).
2- The expression must never end with 'or' or 'and' within a block. For example:

> John and Jane -> OK
>
> John and -> NOT OK
>
> (John and) -> NOT OK
>
> John or -> NOT OK
>
> (John or) -> NOT OK

So it always:

[Optional parentheses] WORD [Optional operation and or][Optional parentheses]

I came up with this but it's not enough but it's a start.

```
\b\w.*(?=or|and).*\w
```

That works for the content with parentheses

Note:
I don't care about the amount of whitespace between words.

The user can combine these expression blocks multiple times.

Comment: Have a look at [`^\w+(?:\s+(?:or|and)\s+\w+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/gD8eW5/1). Instead of `\w+`, you can have `(?:John|Jane)`.

Comment: If there must be optional parentheses: [`^\(?\w+(?:\s+(?:or|and)\s+\w+)*\)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/gD8eW5/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^\(?((\w+|\((?1)\))\s+(?>and|or)\s+(\w+|\((?1)\)))\)?$
```

I didn't think it could be done, but then I found recursion.
https://regex101.com/r/aD7dT0/4

**EDIT 1:** This was broken, fixed it

**EDIT 2:** Made a better regex + it does parenthesis validation, with the exception of parenthesis around the entire statement

Comment: Im going to clean this up, its pretty gross as of https://regex101.com/r/aD7dT0/2

Comment: TIL all about regex recursion, shoutout to the regex debugger on regex101

Comment: Excellent work, did not think it could be done either, excellent!